# DFS maze issue how to find neighbours

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, graph-algorithm, maze

I am completely new in figuring out how graph works (DFS). I have read many tutorials about how to build a maze path finding solver with DFS, and there is one part I don't get. How in the world do I find out who the neighbours to a vertex is?
Forinstens I have this maze:
[maze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A32UK.png)

I have placed all the strings into a two dimensional array called 'names'. So if I forinstens write:

```
names[0,0]  // it contains the string    +
```

if I write:

```
names[0,1] // it contains the string     -
```

if I write:

```
names[1,0]  //it contains the string     B
```

etc. But how does names[1,0] knows its neighbours are names[0,0], names[2,0] and names[1,1] ?

Comment: You build a Node class with four properties : Up, Down, Left, Right which indicates if a Node has a neighbor for each of the four directions.  So your maze is Node[,] maze.

Comment: @jdweng but how does a node knows if it has a neighbour? Forinstens lets say we have a directed graph where A points to B. How does A knows it points to B and how does B knows it doesnt point to a? Unless I of course go in and add each neighbour manually to each node? but since there is like 400 nodes, it seems like a bad idea.

Comment: No.  Look at the maze carefully.  Some plus signs have vertical/horizontal line between them and other do not.  A node is the square between 4 plus signs.  There are 4 properties which are booleans (neighbors) : Up, Down, Left, Right which can have vertical/horizontal line.  When the vertical/horizontal line is present the boolean is true which indicates there is NO neighbor since the direction is blocked.  When there is a neighbor (no line) then you can add/subtract 1 to get the neighbor location in the array.

Comment: @jdweng sorry but you lost me completely there? can you give an example in code? The thing I really don't get is I have a two dimensional array with the strings which is great but it seems like I can't use that two dimensional array to find any neighbours. So I need to make a new two dimensional array (a so called adjacency matrix) where I manually points out who is neighbours to who. So lets say [0,0] has [0,1] as a neighbour, do I then place let something in [0,1] and now lets say that [0,5] has [0,6] as a neighbor. How do they based on that knows who is neighbour to who?

Comment: @cop77 You don't need an explicit adjacency matrix. You know the 4 *potential* neighbors of each location. For location `[i,j]`, you can have neighbors of `[i-1,j]`, `[i+1,j]`, `[i,j-1]`, or `[i,j+1]`. If any of these *potential* neighbors is a) outside the maze, or b) filled with something other than a space, it isn't a neighbor.

Comment: @beaker thanks and it makes sense to me     ` static void neighborList(int i, int j)
        {
            if (numbers[i - 1, j] == " ")
            {
                add numbers[i - 1, j] to nbList
            }
            if (numbers[i + 1, j] == " ")
            {
                add numbers[i + 1, j] to nbList
            }
            if (numbers[i, j - 1] == " ")
            {
                add numbers[i, j - 1] to nbList
            }
            if (number[i, j + 1] == " ")
            {
                add numbers[i, j + 1] to nbList
            }
        } `

Comment: @cop77 Just be careful of nodes on the edges. `[0,0]` will have only 2 potential neighbors.

Comment: @beaker Maybe I should say  if (numbers[i - 1] >= 0 && numbers[i - 1] < numbers.Length && numbers[i - 1, j] == " ") { add numbers[i - 1, j] to nbList } And if (numbers[j - 1] >= Height.Top && numbers[j - 1] < Height.Buttom && numbers[j - 1, j] == " ") { add numbers[j - 1, j] to nbList } and the same with the other. It is just many expressions. And how do I add them to a list later, cause it doesn't seem that simple to do with a loop. Forinstens how would you increase the Objects number in a loop? Object1.add( numbers[i-1,j] and Object2.add( numbers[i-1,j] etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

I started the code and loaded 1st row of maze from the link you provided

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;



namespace ConsoleApplication49
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cell maze = new Cell();
            maze.Load();

        }

    }
    public class Cell
    {
        public static Cell[,] maze = new Cell[10, 10];

        public static KeyValuePair<int, int> start = new KeyValuePair<int, int>();
        public static KeyValuePair<int, int> end = new KeyValuePair<int, int>();

        public bool topBlock { get; set; }
        public bool rightBlock { get; set; }
        public bool bottomBlock { get; set; }
        public bool leftBlock { get; set; }

        public void Load()
        {
            start = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0, 0);
            end = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(9, 9);

            maze[0, 0] = new Cell() { topBlock = true, rightBlock = true, bottomBlock = false, leftBlock = false };
            maze[0, 1] = new Cell() { topBlock = true, rightBlock = false, bottomBlock = false, leftBlock = true };
            maze[0, 2] = new Cell() { topBlock = true, rightBlock = true, bottomBlock = false, leftBlock = false };
            maze[0, 3] = new Cell() { topBlock = true, rightBlock = true, bottomBlock = false, leftBlock = true };
            maze[0, 4] = new Cell() { topBlock = true, rightBlock = false, bottomBlock = false, leftBlock = true };
            maze[0, 5] = new Cell() { topBlock = true, rightBlock = false, bottomBlock = true, leftBlock = false };
            maze[0, 6] = new Cell() { topBlock = true, rightBlock = true, bottomBlock = false, leftBlock = false };
            maze[0, 7] = new Cell() { topBlock = true, rightBlock = false, bottomBlock = false, leftBlock = true };
            maze[0, 8] = new Cell() { topBlock = true, rightBlock = false, bottomBlock = true, leftBlock = false };
            maze[0, 9] = new Cell() { topBlock = true, rightBlock = true, bottomBlock = false, leftBlock = false };
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have a method for defining a maze.  It could be an input file instead of hard coding.  Using some intelligent packing scheme like making top line = 1, right line = 2, bottom line = 4, left line = 8.  The entire maze can be defined like this :

```
            int[,] maze = {
                          {0x39,0x3B,0x95,0x39,0x53},
                          {0xC6,0xC4,0x6B,0xAB,0x32},
                          {0x95,0x3D,0x3A,0x83,0xAA},
                          {0xAB,0x85,0x6C,0x68,0x6A},
                          {0xAA,0xC5,0x39,0x3A,0x96},
                          {0xC6,0x93,0xC6,0xC2,0xAB},
                          {0xD5,0x2C,0x17,0x92,0xC6},
                          {0x95,0x6D,0x45,0x6C,0x3B},
                          {0xC5,0x55,0x39,0x57,0x86},
                          {0xD5,0x55,0x6C,0x55,0x45}
                          };
```